# Problem for secondary school .

Tags: geometry

$ABCD$ is  a square of the plane where
$AB = 2$ and **(C)** is a circle with center  and radius 2.

$ M$ is a point of the arc $\widehat{}$ , different from  and different from  , The tangent **(T)** to the circle **(C)** at point $$ intersects the segment $[]$ at $$
and  $[]$ in  , We put $KB =x $  and  $ LB = y$.

What is the easiest way to prove to secondary school students that
$ KL = 4 - x-y       $ .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider a point exterior to a circle.  Then consider the two tangent segments from that point to the circle.

Comment: Try to put this in a comment :)

Comment: Do secondary school students know that $ AK = KM $ and similarly $ ML = LC $?

Comment: @ Mohammad Ali Nematollahi
Yes, that's the idea of ​​proof, but I don't have any idea to prove it.

Comment: @mlc $ KL = KM + ML = AK + LC = (2 - x) + (2 - y) = 4 - x - y $

Comment: @ Mohammad Ali NematollahiI 
want to know what it is that allows us to say that $ AK=KM$ and  $ML=LC $

Comment: @mlc To prove $\lvert AK\rvert=\lvert KM\rvert$, for example, add the line segment $DK$, then you have that $\triangle DAK\cong\triangle DMK$ (e.g., using SSS since, with $2$ sides equal to each other among the triangles, and both being right-angled triangles, then the Pythagorean Theorem proves the corresponding third triangle sides are also equal).

Comment: @John Omielan               Thank you sir, best idea.

Answer (score 1):

[image]My students would give you the answer $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$
To find your answer you have to suggest some help lines to show that the red and green triangles are congruent, so you have KM=AK=2-x and ML=BL=2-y

Answer (score 0):

Assume D is at the origin, $(0,0)$.

M is on a line passing through the origin. If M has coordinates $(a,b)$ the slope of the line connecting it to the origin is $b/a$. The tangent line to the circle is perpendicular to this line, thus it has slope $-a/b$. Given a point on the tangent line and the slope of the tangent line you can find the points where it intersects the square. This gives you the coordinates of $K$ and $L$.

Now you know the coordinates of all points in the problem, so you can use the distance formula to find the relevant distances and demonstrate the relationship in question.